# Formatting text for a combobox, C#

Tags: c#, winforms, string, combobox

I have three values I need to align in a dropdown box. How can I do this? I've been trying this:

`String.Format("{0,-30}{1,-15}{2,-10}{3,-8}", new object[] { cusJob, service, username, time });`

But that leaves it uneven because it's not a monospaced font. I don't really want to use a monospaced font and I've seen applications align it before so how can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the DropDownList's DrawMode to OwnerDrawFixed and render the items in the DrawItem event handler.

Examples are [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/CheckComboBox.aspx) and [here](http://www.mctainsh.com/Articles/Csharp/ComboBoxColor.aspx) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/0438b63a-5f6b-401c-8ea9-cd9e950ed6e1/), but there are lot more to be found on the web, if you search for "dropdownlist ownerdraw columns drawmode".

Comment: The third example helped the most

Answer (score -1):

in your string you could use the **\t** control char (tab) to tab out the values, although some more string-manip might need to be done to work out how many tabs you need to put in the string.

**Edit:** for vb.net see the **controlchars** class

Comment: \t's show up as little boxes instead of tabs, as do all the control characters